# Produce Protobuf message using Rest proxy API

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-cloud, kafka-rest

I am exploring options to integrate an ITSM system with Kafka. This needs Protobuf messages sent to Kafka via rest proxy API.

I followed below two articles and set the request body and headers.

https://quachtd.com/using-kafka-rest-proxy-with-protobuf/

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/quickstart.html#produce-and-consume-protobuf-messages

On Confluent, I have created a topic and a schema for testing. Though I am able to produce a message under the topic via JSON, I am not able to produce Protobuf messages.

I am not even able to test the ‘GET’ method as I am not able to find the SchemaRegistryHost and port. How can get these details from the Confluent console?
http://{SchemaRegistryHost}:{SchemaRegistryPort}/subjects/salesorder_topic-value/versions/1

Though I took the Schema ID manually and supplied it in the input, I received the message “{“error_code”:405,“message”:“HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed”}”. This made me think if there is any action needed on Schema for the ‘POST’ method to work.

Aside, as this is not JSON, I wonder if I could not test this out in Postman. If it’s possible how can I test it otherwise what other tools can help me to perform the test?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLqcx.png)

Comment: What do you mean "Confluent Console"? Control Center? Or CLI? You don't need Schema Registry address to send data to the REST proxy

Comment: Your first two links are referencing using the REST Proxy as a standalone installation, not the Confluent Cloud REST API https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding a schema to the registry you have to set the mode to IMPORT.

The mode parameter defines which operations are allowed on schemas.

```
IMPORT
READONLY
READWRITE
```

The first one allows to import a schema and specify id and version.

You can set the mode for all subjects or on a specific subject.
To enable mode changes on Schema Registry, you have to set the following properties in the Schema Registry properties file before starting it:

mode.mutability=true

With curl you might use the command:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://{SchemaRegistryHost}:{SchemaRegistryPort}/mode --data '{"mode": "IMPORT"}'
```

Comment: Notice OP says "not able to find the SchemaRegistryHost and port".